# How can I seperate and transform multi line .txt file to double line in python

Tags: python, txt

I used OpenSeesPy library to get some analysis data from python. I saved analysis results as .txt format. I have two lines in .txt file but without comma. I cannot read this file seperated two columns. How can I get it? Sample .txt output like that;

#### Column.txt

```py
{-0.354232 -1.41907e-05,
-1.71694 -6.93533e-05,
-2.65529 -0.000107973,
-3.53774 -0.000144827,
-4.39713 -0.000181259}
```

I want to obtain this file as two readable columns in python.

Comment: So if I understand your question correctly, you want each pair of values to be split off into two columns like so?

column_x = [-0.354232, -1.71694, -2.65529, -3.53774, -4.39713], column_y = [-1.41907e-05, -6.93533e-05, -0.000107973, -0.000144827, -0.000181259]

Correct me if I misinterpreted your question, but you should be able to do that using Pythons string functions.

Comment: Hi @gollum18 actually in this .txt file first and second columns are giving different results from the analysis. I want to use both of it for plotting (X and Y) I did it before in VBA with same file but I did not find anyway to get datas as X and Y in python. Sorry gollum I missed some sentences in your messages. Yes I want this actually. I tried some functions to get but I did not seperated datas. I still see one column with two datas.

Comment: If it is like as gollum18 said, you can just split the string with comma then split each element of the list with white-space. Should be easy. If you provide more elaboration on what exactly you want to do, we can help better.

Comment: Hi @AbdurRakib yes I want to get data exactly that gollum18 said. My last comment could been helped you?

Comment: If the file has different values than analysis then that's a problem with the analysis output. Anyway, if you want it that way then assuming the txt file has a one line text, i.e., no newline in between, then this code should work. `file = open("Sample.txt", 'r')`
`line = file.readline()`
`line = line.strip("Colum.txt")`
`line = line.strip("=")`
`line = line.strip("{")`
`line = line.strip("}")`
`line = line.strip("\n")`
`line = line.split(",")`
`temp = [x.split(" ") for x in line]`
`X = [float(x[0]) for x in temp]`
`Y = [float(x[1]) for x in temp]`

Comment: It's a dumb but easy way to write it. There are more elegant way of writing it.

Comment: @AbdurRakib thank you for help! I solved with your idea and shared the code lines below.

Answer (score 1):

Well I solved this problem with helps that shared in comments. Thanks. Here is the code lines that I used.

```
with open('Column.txt') as f:
    coords = f.read().split()
x_coords = coords[0::2]
y_coords = coords[1::2]

xcor = pd.DataFrame(x_coords)
ycor = pd.DataFrame(y_coords)

xcor_reel = xcor.select_dtypes(include='object').columns
xcor[xcor_reel] = xcor[xcor_reel].astype("float")
ycor_reel = ycor.select_dtypes(include='object').columns
ycor[ycor_reel] = ycor[ycor_reel].astype("float")

ax = ycor.plot()

xcor.plot(ax=ax)
```

Comment: If the file looks like that, it's a very simple process and doesn't even require `pandas` or anything complicated. It's just a simple loop of reading line by line, purging unnecessary characters and splitting into list. I do that most of the time. Almost every experiment data I get are in some similar format with thousands of lines and I just let `python` do my dirty work.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, this can also be done without `pandas`:

```py
data = """{-0.354232 -1.41907e-05,
-1.71694 -6.93533e-05,
-2.65529 -0.000107973,
-3.53774 -0.000144827,
-4.39713 -0.000181259}""" # obtained from open("Columns.txt").read()

data = data.strip("{}")
lines = data.split("\n")
output = {}
for line in lines:
    xcor, ycor = line.split(" ")
    output[xcor] = ycor
print(" ".join(output.keys()))
print(" ".join(output.values()))
```